# How do I return a class member that is an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, return-type

Trying to get the return function to return the full array, but not able to do it with a for loop or without. Is there any way to get this done?

```java
public class Teams {
    
    String Game;
    String Coach;
    String Player[];
    
    public void setPlayer(String a[])
    {
       
        for (int i = 2; i<10; i++)
        {
            Player[i-2] = a[i];
        }
    }
    
    public String getPlayer()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            return Player[i];
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Following Java naming conventions helps make your code readable. Variable names start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about arrays - you can return the member as is:

```
public String[] getPlayer() {
    return Player;
}
```

Comment: Good Answer. Perhaps that method should be named in plural, `getPlayers`.

Comment: @BasilBourque I kept the naming from the OP's naming (note that the data member is also called `Player` although it's an array). However, I agree that `getPlayers` would be a better name.